# ConTeXt: aligning multiline content in columns within a makeup

Tags: context

I'm working on some presentation slides in ConTeXt and I can't figure out how to achieve top/bottom/middle vertical alignment of multiline content across two columns. Further complicating the issue is that I am using global vertical alignment using a makeup (which seems to throw off columnset).

I have tried 3 things, all of which have some issues (example code below):

1. `paragraphs` don't seem to have any alignment support (and using them for multiline content seems to abuse what they are meant for)
2. `placefigure` combined with `combination` allows for different alignment options, but doesn't seem to support multiline content (I also tried adding a `vbox`, but that throws off the horizontal spacing)
3. `columnset` makes document compilation freeze if placed within a makeup (and doesn't seem to support vertical alignment anyway)

Example code using a couple of tikz pictures. I would like the option to align the two columns vertically by top/bottom/middle:

```
%&context

% Loading tikz
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

% Define vertical centering
\definemakeup[Center]

\starttext

%------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paragraph

\defineparagraphs[ParColumns][n=2]
\setupparagraphs[ParColumns][1][width=.5\textwidth]
% no way to define vertical alignment?

\startCentermakeup

  \startParColumns

    \starttikzpicture
      \node[draw, minimum height=1cm] (test1) {Left graphic};
    \stoptikzpicture

    \blank[small]

    Some descriptive text

  \nextParColumns

    \starttikzpicture
      \node[draw, minimum height=3cm] (test2) {Right graphic};
    \stoptikzpicture

  \stopParColumns

\stopCentermakeup

\stoptext
```

Using `placefigure` without `vbox` around left side content removes the linebreak between left graphic and text. Adding `vbox` around the content introduces a massive horizontal space.

```
%&context

% Loading tikz
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

% Define vertical centering
\definemakeup[Center]

\starttext

%------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Combinations

\startCentermakeup

\placefigure[here,none]{}{

  \startcombination[2*1, location=middle]

    {
    \starttikzpicture
      \node[draw, minimum height=1cm] (test1) {Left graphic};
    \stoptikzpicture

    \blank[small]

    Some descriptive text
    }{}

    {
    \starttikzpicture
      \node[draw, minimum height=3cm] (test2) {Right graphic};
    \stoptikzpicture

    }{}

  \stopcombination
}

\stopCentermakeup

\stoptext
```

This is what happens if I add `vbox` (with frame for clarity):

[image: With vbox]

Comment: I included tikz code because I'm currently working with some existing tikz graphics (and I don't know if tikz might be adding any issues of its own)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want content to flow from one column to another, you can use `TABLE`s and control the vertical alignment of columns using `align` key (`low`|`high`|`lohi`). Here is an example:

```
\setuppapersize[S5]

% Loading tikz
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

% Define vertical centering
\definemakeup[Center]

\startsetups columns
  \setupTABLE[row][1][width=0.5\textwidth, height=\textheight]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startCentermakeup
  \startTABLE[setups=columns]
    \NC[align=low] 
        \starttikzpicture
          \node[draw, minimum height=1cm] (test1) {Left graphic};
        \stoptikzpicture

        \blank[small]

        Some descriptive text
    \NC[align=lohi]
        \starttikzpicture
          \node[draw, minimum height=3cm] (test2) {Right graphic};
        \stoptikzpicture

    \NC \NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopCentermakeup
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

If you want finer control, then you can use layers.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid the extra markup of tables, but the `\startsetups` solution is quite nice. I don't think I saw it in the wiki. I also didn't know that you can use the `\NC` notation with `TABLE` rather than `\bTD \eTD`.

Comment: @ssokolen:  See [this blog post](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/formatting-tables/) for my thoughts on formatting tables.

Comment: That's really helpful -- I'll definitely be using that approach for future tables.